# How do I teleport a player based on their score?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I teleport a player based on their score? What I want to do is if a player goes below zero (money) on the score board they will be teleported to a certain location. I’m on bedrock 1.16 - here's my code so far, but this does not work:

```
/execute if @a[scores={money=..0}] run tp 1908 64 -1293
```

Answer (score 3):

Try running:

```
tp @a[scores={money=0}] 1908 64 -1293
```

This selects any player with a score of *exactly* zero, and then teleports them. The `/execute` command you tried to use doesn’t work like that in Bedrock and wouldn’t have worked anyway.